# Oboe.js, Promises, and Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, oboe.js

I'm using [Oboe.js](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js), [oboe-promise](https://github.com/kinday/oboe-promise) (wraps oboe calls in a promise), and [Jest](https://jestjs.io/). I'm probably doing something stupid. Any suggestions? Thanks.

**My code**

```
"use strict";

const oboe = require('oboe-promise')
const { Readable } = require('stream')

class Example {

  async run() {
    const json = JSON.stringify([{obj1: {name: 'example', value: 5}}, {obj2: {type: 'other', value: 0}}])
    const strm = Readable.from(json)

    return await oboe(strm)
      .node('{type}', (node) => {
        node.name = node.type
        delete node.type

        return node
      })
      .run()
  }  
}

module.exports = Example
```

**My test file**

```
"use strict"

// Classes
let Example // class under test

// Objects
let example  // object under test

describe('Example', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    Example = require('../../src/Example')
    
    example = new Example()
  })

  test('run', async () => {
    expect(await example.run()).toEqual(JSON.stringify([{obj1: {name: 'example', value: 5}}, {obj2: {value: 0, name: 'other'}}]))
  })
})
```

When I run my Jest test I get "Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout." I've added jest.setTimeout(60000) and get same result. I have other Jest tests that test asynchronous non-oboe code and they work fine using the async/await

```
test('run', async () => {
    expect(await <codeToTest>).toEqual(<expected>)
  })
```

pattern.

The code works if I run the code outside of Jest using:

```
"use strict";

const Example = require('./Example')

function runIt() {
  const ex = new Example()
  ex.run()
    .then(r => {console.log(r)})
    .catch(e => {console.log(e)})
}

runIt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I switched from Jest to Mocha and now the tests work.